# 2D Image inside 3D mesh in vispy

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, 2d, vispy

I am working on rendering a 3D mesh in vispy with custom camera movements. The 3D mesh is generated from a pointcloud.

I however have a part of mesh which is just a flat cardboard image. To speed up rendering I want to treat it as a 2D image.

From vispy, I have a SceneCanvas object which I can populate with Mesh like so.

```
canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(bgcolor=bgcolor)
view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera.fov = 50
mesh = visuals.Mesh(shading=None)
view.add(mesh)
mesh.set_data(vertices=verts, faces=faces, vertex_colors=colors)
```

My question is that can I add a 2D image in this mesh? Using ImageVisual module of vispy.

```
2d_img_to_be_inserted_in_3d_mesh = visuals.image.ImageVisual()
```

If so, how can I do it?
If not, is it possible to do in some other way?

Comment: What do you mean by "add a 2D image in this mesh"? One mistake I think I see in your code is that you should be using visuals from `vispy.scene.visuals` instead of `vispy.visuals` (this is an unfortunate structure/requirement). So you would use `vispy.scene.visuals.Mesh` and `vispy.scene.visuals.Image`. They would be two separate Visuals.

Comment: So, actually I import `visuals` like so.
`from vispy.scene import visuals`. 

"add a 2D image in this mesh" means attaching an image as a texture to 3D rectangle, instead of treating each image pixel as a separate 3D point.

Comment: Ok so applying the texture *on* the mesh. If we're talking about the same thing then check out this example https://vispy.org/gallery/scene/mesh_texture.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scene-mesh-texture-py and its use of TextureFilter.

Comment: Great! I'll check it out and ask again if that does not work.